# Help Finding a Childs Book back in the 80's or Early 90's

Tags: story-identification, books

It involved a group of children who were also monsters. The book had a background story where they were talking about a bad movie that was about a severed hand that was going around attacking people and then the monster children were being followed around in real life by the Hand from the movie.

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer. It was [Fifth Grade Monsters Series](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pe.cgi?7121) by Mel Gilden, illustrated by John Pierard.

Comment: Congrats! I believe you should be able to accept your answer immediately.